What's in my shampoo mystery water?
I just noticed the primary ingredient in my L'Oreal shampoo is 1101573PT20 Aqua. In the corresponding conditioner it is 1067691PT30 Aqua. Last I knew, water didn't have specific alphanumeric designators. Google AI says it's a solvent. Gee thanks. I'm wondering what happens when this fancy alphanumerically designated water/solvent gets into my eyes and mucus membranes. Anyone out there care to elaborate on the alphanumeric mystery water?

Never seen this name on a shampoo label. Can you post an image?

The only reasonable way to get answer is to ask L'Oreal. There is also possibility the code does not relate to water at all.

I checked the L'Oreal shampoo images, none of them write anything like this.

Looks like an in-house designation for an ingredient, which might even refer to another item in the list. That is much better than an outhouse ingredient, which you would not want in conditioner or sham poo. ;-)

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65865/why-do-shampoo-ingredient-labels-feature-the-term-aqua

@ACR See: https://stopandshop.com/groceries/health-beauty/hair-care/conditioner/moisturizing-conditioner/loreal-elvive-total-repair-5-repairing-conditioner-28-oz-btl.html

Have you tried to look for this name in the INCI (International Nomenclature of Cosmetic Ingredients)?

I posted a picture of the ingredients from the bottles. I actually googled the alphanumeric designator and the only thing that populates is that it's an ingredient in L'Oreal shampoo etc. I'm sure the images are blurry but it's the very 1st ingredient on both. At this point, I'm determined to know. I've also noticed different batches of the product have slightly different alphanumeric designators. I suppose I'm going to have to contact L'Oreal.
